# FlexiAuth:password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: 20 expecting 22

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, php-password-hash

I upgraded from Codeigniter 2.2.x to Codeigniter 3.0.x. Since my project uses FlexiAuth, I downloaded Reconix/Flexi-Auth-CI3 changes.

The PHP version is PHP 5.6

However, when I try to login as an existing user in my database, I get the following error:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: 20 expecting 22</p>
<p>Filename: models/Flexi_auth_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1054</p>
```

In Codeigniter's applications/config/config.php, I have:

```
$config['security']['static_salt']='MY_SALT_VALUE';
```

I don't know where the problem lies. I want to be able to have my existing users login.

Help!

**EDITED 3/20 to add more info:** FlexiAuth model code snippet for `verify_password()` looks as follows:

```
$database_password = <retrieves the stored db pw>
$database_salt = <retrieves the stored db salt >
$static_salt = $this->auth->auth_security['static_salt'];//My supplied value
$data["salt"]=$static_salt.$database_salt; 

if( password_hash($verify_password, 1, $data) == $database_password){
    $match=true;
    if (password_needs_rehash($database_password, 1)) {
       // store new hash in database
       $this->__save_rehashed_password($identity,  $verify_password); 
    }
    ....
}
```

But since my original user hash was too short, it never gets to a comparison let alone a need to rehash. Per *@MagnusEriksson's* suggestion I tried not supplying the user-supplied hash and it failed too.... Has anyone else encountered and overcome this while migrating to CI3?

mmiz

Comment: How long is your `static_salt`? 20 characters?

Comment: Check if you can omit the salt altogether. `password_hash()` automatically generates a strong and secure salt if none is passed. The "salt" option for `password_hash()` is even deprecated in PHP 7 since generating your own secure salt is way more complicated than people think.

Comment: @deceze - OK -so my static_salt length (carried over from the CI-2 config) is 12 characters long. The database_salt is the default 10 characters long. Which explains the 20 in the error message. Where is the comparison value 22 from? Also, if I were to change my static_salt, won't it invalidate all the existing passwords? (Or is my understanding of that flawed?)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - if I omit the salt altogether, the password verification (which uses password_hash to compare the submitted pw to the one stored in the database) fails flat out.

Comment: You mean that it uses `password_verify()` to compare a password with a hash? That should still work since the salt is a part of the hash. If removing the user defined salt makes the verification fail, then the library can't be using those functions correctly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - I added a bit more detail in the question itself. I was not able to make any headway with not using the user defined salt.